# Strange behavior of ternary operator

Tags: grails, groovy

I observed strange behavior, in clean "test" application I have this simple controller:

(Grails 2.5.0, Java Oracle 8u45, GNU/Linux Debian 7)

```
package test
class DiController {

    def ok() {
        double d = 0d
        int i = (int)d
        def r = []
        r << i
        if (true) {
            r << i
        }
        else {
            r << d
        }
        if (false) {
            r << i
        }
        else {
            r << d
        }
        render r.toString()
    }

    def bug() {
        double d = 0d
        int i = (int)d
        def r = []
        r << i
        r << (true ? i : d) // why Integer will be serialized like Double ?
        r << (false ? i : d)
        render r.toString()
    }
}
```

/test/di/ok renders `[0, 0, 0.0]`, but /test/di/bug renders `[0, 0.0, 0.0]`.

It seems that ternary operator converts the result value, but I haven't observed such conversion in Groovy console. Is this Grails specific?

(Graeme Rocher marked this as "not a bug" here: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/8994, so it should be known behavior)

**EDIT:** I used older Groovy (1.8.6) for tests "out of Grails", Groovy 2.4.3 has described behavior (gives `[0, 0.0, 0.0]`), so it has really nothing to do with Grails.

Comment: could you please add for reference, a ticket/url/... where the "not a bug" was claimed?

Comment: Added link to question

Comment: I get `[0, 0.0, 0.0]` in Groovy shell with Groovy 2.3.4 Java 8u45

Comment: @doelleri Thanks, I realized I used groovyConsole in system, which is a little outdated (Groovy 1.8.6), the 2.4.3 returns `[0, 0.0, 0.0]`. So definitely is Groovy thing (and obviously the behavior has changed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that's because Groovy tries to find a common ground for incompatible types. This is an example of various ternary operators uses:

```
println ((true ? (0 as Integer) : (0.0 as Float)).class)
println ((true ? (0 as Float) : (0.0 as Double)).class)
println ((true ? (0 as Integer) : (0 as Long)).class)
println ((true ? (0 as Integer) : (0 as Byte)).class)
```

and that's how Groovy compiles this into Java

```
var1[1].callCurrent(this, var1[2].callGetProperty(true?(Float)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType((Integer)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType(Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.class), Float.class):(Float)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType($const$0, Float.class)));
var1[3].callCurrent(this, var1[4].callGetProperty(true?(Double)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType((Float)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType(Integer.valueOf(0), Float.class), Double.class):(Double)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType($const$0, Double.class)));
var1[5].callCurrent(this, var1[6].callGetProperty(true?(Long)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType((Integer)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType(Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.class), Long.class):(Long)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType(Integer.valueOf(0), Long.class)));
var1[7].callCurrent(this, var1[8].callGetProperty(true?(Integer)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType(Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.class):(Integer)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType((Byte)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType(Integer.valueOf(0), Byte.class), Integer.class)));
```

In all cases it does a lot of type conversions just to agree both true/false result branch and make them return the same type. Surprisingly this is the case only for numerical values. Other values are treated differently.

```
println ((true ? ("s") : (0 as Byte)).class)
println ((false ? ("s") : (0 as Byte)).class)
println ((true ? (new Date()) : (0 as Byte)).class)
```

gets translated into Java like

```
var1[9].callCurrent(this, var1[10].callGetProperty(true?"s":(Byte)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType(Integer.valueOf(0), Byte.class)));
var1[11].callCurrent(this, var1[12].callGetProperty(false?"s":(Byte)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType(Integer.valueOf(0), Byte.class)));
var1[13].callCurrent(this, var1[14].callGetProperty(true?var1[15].callConstructor(Date.class):(Byte)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType(Integer.valueOf(0), Byte.class)));
```

It doesn't answer **why** that happens but answers *how* that happened. At least I hope so.

Comment: may I ask what decompiler you used for this? Because that Java is quite off

Comment: Thanks! The conversion of numeric type to "wider" type seems in Groovy pretty common to me, so I don't find it so strange anymore (...also after realising I used older Groovy for tests "out of grails").